# How long to walk across the continent in Elder Scrolls Online?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

The world of The Elder Scrolls Online is huge.

About how long in real life does it take to walk across the continent, east-to-west?

Comment: Interesting question. Onething that's kinda unclear: do you mean in a straight line or while also passing all zones?

Comment: You won't even be able to cross it. I don't know if it has changed since then, but the last time I played it, I tried to go to the other side of the continent but at some point I was blocked because not my race/territory.
So in the end you don't really have much to explore in that game.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/elderscrollsonline/comments/1jzdnv/you_guys_probably_already_figured_out_a_ballpark/

Comment: @Jutschge In as straight a line as possible. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky for you somebody did exactly this! User u/ansem119 on Reddit [trekked across the continent](https://www.reddit.com/r/elderscrollsonline/comments/8bv6w1/discussion_i_walked_across_tamriel_to_see_how/) in ESO. According to him it took an hour and thirteen minutes to cross the world East to West, not including loading times.

He writes:

> So I don't know exactly why I wanted to do it, I thought it would be interesting to know how big the map was in terms of walking across it. The rules I had was not using sprint and I avoided straying too far away from paths so I encountered less mobs.
>
> Here are all the paths I used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/snlOM.jpg
>
> I didn't include loading times and a bit of Cyrodiil was estimated because the beginning and end bits were blocked off for me. I also wasn't 100% sure where the north morrowind gate lined up with so i just decided to walked half way through the rift and then i just stopped the timer there and continued at the northern morrowind gate when i got there.
>
> Other than that the rest was pretty accurate. The total time added up to around 1 hour 13 minutes and 55 seconds of walking from the dock in East Deshaan to the dock in West Glenumbra.